# DialogFlow CX WebhookRequest object is null

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Good Day!

I am looking to integrate a .net c# application with my current DialogFlow CX Agent.

However, when I call a webhook with:

- Generic WebService
- Subtype = Standard
- No authentication

I receive no WebHookRequest Object

Please see my code to try and extract this, when i set a break-point and step through the code, the object is null right away.

```
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public string TestDialogFlowWebhook([FromBody] WebhookRequest request)
        {
            string temp = "";

            Console.WriteLine(request);
            return temp;
        }
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on what to try, or read, to try to figure this out?

When I call a google function with the webhook, it does sent the WebHookRequest object, but just not to my .net code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the protobuf classes. see my examples in golang and in TS:

https://github.com/xavidop/dialogflow-cx-webhook-go/blob/main/function.go

https://github.com/xavidop/dialogflow-cx-webhook-typescript/blob/main/src/index.ts